# Is there a way to modify the response data in TypeScript (React) if the actual data body is different than the type defined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently building an ecommerce application for my company. And as the title, I'm facing a problem like this:
Usually, my product types from the API call would be something like:

```
content: [
    isAvailable: boolean;
    isSoldOut: boolean;
    product: {
      id: string;
      productName: string;
    }
    seller: string;
  ]
```

But in a minor of cases, the actual response would be like:

```
content: {
    id: string;
    productName: string;
    ...
  } []
```

*basically only the body of the product, no extra information like the above*

So in short, I just want to modify the response of the API (the minor-case one or the other way around) without having to touch the already-defined product.type.ts.

I did add an extra interface for this, but it made the app very complicated since I was trying to pass the data conditionally to any of the children components that use that data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest to create [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check which data came and then work with these types (modify that not common one to common one or count with both types in every component)

```
const isMajorType(data: Major | Minor): data is Major {
return "isAvailable" in data
}

const transformData = (data: Major | Minor): Major =>{
if(isMajorType(data)){
return data
}
return // some transform magic
}
```

Comment: 1. the above solution is what you need from TS.
2. but the major problem is that backend response is not consistent (if it is one endpoint that can return two completely different structures. I don't know what reasons stand for that but it could have been made simpler :)

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. I dont know what my API team are thinking, but they are giving me 2 different responses for getting the products. I'm just trying to go with it while asking them for correction.